# Setting terminal Vim color scheme on Mac Lion

Tags: vim, macvim

I just updated my Mac to lion and I am trying to configure bash and vim color schemes.

I created `~/.vim/colors` folder and put the color schemes in there.  For some reason the text colors are all the same.  So it would be either all green, all cyan, or all yellow. And it happens the same for macvim and terminal vim.

Right before I started configuring stuff, I installed the CSApprox plugin.  Maybe that is somehow preventing it from working right.

How do I set terminal Vim color scheme on Mac Lion?

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'the text colors are all the same'?  That for all of the different colour schemes they all have the same colour text?  Or that every piece of text in a file is always coloured the same colour?  Or something else?

Comment: Also `syntax` is off by default.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add

```
:syntax on
```

to my .vimrc, and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can try `gvim` if possible.  If it's ok, then something about the `terminal` cause the trouble.  If `gvim` get same trouble, it shows `vim` plugin or configurations (in the .vimrc file) would be the reason.  By this way, it might be avoided to unnecessarily delete plugins or re-configurations.